# How To Remove Before Filter SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

My Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tvn_Listing 
LEFT JOIN tvn_ListingOption ON (tvn_Listing.id = tvn_ListingOption.listings_id 
                                AND tvn_ListingOption.options_id = 12)
```

How to remove null record when I left join two table? 
My query returns a result that is not what the conditions specify.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give example data and output?

Comment: Have you tried `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly the problem is:

You get records from `tvn_Listing` table which have `NULL` values from the `LEFT JOIN`ed table `tvn_ListingOption`. Well you can check for null values in `tvn_ListingOption` table like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tvn_Listing 
LEFT JOIN tvn_ListingOption ON (tvn_Listing.id = tvn_ListingOption.listings_id 
                                AND tvn_ListingOption.options_id = 12)
WHERE tvn_ListingOption.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Why would you not just use an inner join?

Comment: +1 an `inner join` improves clarity of the code by removing complexities

Comment: definitely if there are only these two tables involved that is the way to go. But I'm doubtful there might be other tables involved but sample here only shows 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that where you add the NOT NULL condition will affect the results (if options_id is NULLABLE)

```
test=# select * from tvn_Listing;
 id | nm 
----+----
  1 | A
  2 | B
(2 rows)

test=# select * from tvn_listingoption ;
 id | op 
----+----
  1 | A
  3 | B
    | D
(3 rows)

test=# select * from tvn_listing left join tvn_listingoption on tvn_listing.id=tvn_listingoption.id;
 id | nm | id | op 
----+----+----+----
  1 | A  |  1 | A
  2 | B  |    | 
(2 rows)

test=# select * from tvn_listing left join tvn_listingoption on tvn_listing.id=tvn_listingoption.id and tvn_listingoption.id is not null ;
 id | nm | id | op 
----+----+----+----
  1 | A  |  1 | A
  2 | B  |    | 
(2 rows)

test=# select * from tvn_listing left join tvn_listingoption on tvn_listing.id=tvn_listingoption.id where  tvn_listingoption.id is not null ;
 id | nm | id | op 
----+----+----+----
  1 | A  |  1 | A
(1 row)
```